# Seaside in Pharo Smalltalk - How do I enable opening the "classic" debugger (error handler) when an exception occurs?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Seaside in Pharo Smalltalk - How do I enable opening the "classic" debugger when an exception occurs?

Right now my WAComponents display an exception error in the webpage viewing the Seaside App. Is it possible to raise in exception in the image itself and have the 'classic' debugger pop up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via the Seaside config interface (http://localhost:8080/config/) of your app, go to the 'Filters' section and hit the 'Configure' button for the WAExceptionFilter. Choose `WADebugErrorHandler` or `WAWalkbackErrorHandler`.

Programmatically:

```
(WAAdmin defaultDispatcher handlerAt: 'MyApp') 
    exceptionHandler: WADebugErrorHandler
```

Comment: Just for reference: you're talking about Seaside 3, not 2.8.

Comment: @MaxLeske - What is different about Seaside 2.8?

Comment: Nearly everything :) For instance, `WAAdmin` doesn't exist. I'm pretty sure though that you're using version 3. I just wanted to point out the difference to other readers.

Comment: And for those wondering what happened with 2.9? That only was a beta. The changes were so large that a major version update was made